# Trigger gradle task when running instrumented tests from AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am currently struggling with instrumented tests in AndroidStudio. I have a gradle plugin, which adds dependency for setup & teardown of deterministic environment in emulator (eg. push files into sdcard):

```
class PrepareEnvPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project target) {
        target.afterEvaluate { project ->
            project.extensions.findByType(AppExtension)
                    .testVariants
                    .forEach {
                        DefaultTask connectedTask = it.connectedInstrumentTest

                        def setupTask = createSetupTask(project, it)
                        def tearDownTask = createTearDownTask(project, it)

                        connectedTask.dependsOn(setupTask)
                        connectedTask.finalizedBy(tearDownTask)
                    }
        }
    }

    static DefaultTask createSetupTask(Project project, TestVariant variant) {
        return project.tasks.create("setup" + variant.name) {
            doLast {
                // Run adb
            }
        }
    }

    static DefaultTask createTearDownTask(Project project, TestVariant variant) {
        return project.tasks.create("tearDown" + variant.name) {
            doLast {
                // Run adb
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: PrepareEnvPlugin
```

When running tests from terminal using `./gradlew connectedDevDebugAndroidTest`, my tasks are correctly trigger. However running it from AndroidStudio (with "*Run Tests in ...*") seems to completely skip these tasks.

Is there a way how to achieve same behaviour between terminal commands and AS test runner? My ultimate goal is to prepare environment and clean it up for every execution of instrumented tests, no matter whether it runs in terminal or AS. Thanks!